# Find the riddle or its solution

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> You cannot get rid of me now.
>   Before being led around,
>   The middle of one, don't ask how.
>   Apply glue to the two and you've found
>   The thing which you've just solved.
>   It's also down there, below the fold.

**What is the solution of this riddle?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The final answer is

> RIDDLE - the question *and* the solution

---

> 1. You cannot get rid of me now.
> 2. Before being led around,
> 3. The middle of one, don't ask how.
> 4. Apply glue to the two and you've found
> 5. The thing which you've just solved.
> 6. It's also down there, below the fold.

First and third lines:

> Taking 'the middle of one' - we get the middle word of line 1 - **rid**.

Second line:

> Gives **dle** - anagram of led

Fourth and Fifth:

> Putting the two together (apply glue) gives RIDDLE - what we just solved

Sixth:

> The answer 'RIDDLE' is down below the question in the tags

Comment: I think with fold he means what seperates the question with the answers, and your answer, which is also the hidden riddle, is here below that line.

Comment: @RnRoger it could indeed be that... I'm going to wait for confirmation from Rand before adding because I'm pretty sure I've missed some stuff out. Good observation though! :)

Comment: You've got the right answer, but there's a lot of clues you haven't explained. You say "The first two lines contain the words ...", but the riddle is better constructed than that: you're not just meant to pick out random words :-) Also, lines 3 and 6? @RnRoger's guess is close but not quite what I intended.

Comment: @Randal'Thor jut got the 'middle of one' line

Comment: My intended explanation for line 6 was the *tag*, not the answer. Apart from that, perfect. Good job!

Comment: @Randal'Thor ah right - edited

Comment: @Randal'Thor But there's no fold there :p

Comment: You know, for us on the mobile app, the tags are *above* the question, not *below* it...